# How do you export Windows 7 AQS search to file?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell, windows-search

My question is identical to this question that has already been asked back in 2011, but that does not have any answers:

[Export Windows 7 search results to a text file](https://superuser.com/questions/324882/export-windows-7-advanced-search-results-to-text-file)

I'm hoping that someone may have an answer now...

Similar to outputting the results of a command line command to a text file with the greater than sign, I would like to output the results of an AQS search to a file.  Any common parsable file format will do such as CSV or TXT.

My Win 7 AQS query is: "datecreated:4/21/2014 OR datemodified:4/21/2014" and I want to output the list of resulting files in a list file.

I am open to ideas on doing this query in a scripting language such as Powershell, Python, or even a BAT file, if anyone has such ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Select all search result (Ctrl+A), hold the Shift key and right-click any result item. Choose **Copy as path** from the context-menu, and paste it wherever you like. Paths are inside straight quotes and you'll need to manually remove them if required. Would that work for you?

Comment: That works for my purposes.  A bit more work than I'd like, but I guess a little extra work won't hurt me any.  It is, after all, only mouse clicks and keystrokes.  If you would please, create your comment as an answer, so can give you the compensation you so deserve.

Comment: Instead of duplicating a question, [place a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) (and comments) on the existing question to draw attention to it. Actually [the question](http://superuser.com/questions/324882/export-windows-7-advanced-search-results-to-text-file) intrigues me enough, so I'll stick a bounty on it myself. :)  If you want even more attention add your own bounty to it. :)

Comment: techie007 - As you may or may have not noticed, I do not have enough reputation to create a bounty (minimum of 50 rep), otherwise I would have considered doing so.

Comment: @PTW-105 Then I would suggest participating in the site to gain some rep.  This isn't a take-all-you-want site, you have to give a little. ;)

Comment: @techie007 I certainly agree.  At this moment I would just like and31415 to post his comment as an answer so that I can give him the credit he is due.  Regardless, I appreciate your advice and certainly will hold it near and dear to my heart going forward in my involvement in this community. ;)

Comment: Since it seems that I can only edit a post once...

@and31415 Can you re-post your comment as a proposed answer such that I can mark it as the answer and award you your due credit?

Comment: @PTW-105 I've added the answer in the linked question as well as here. I've expanded the comment to provide further information, as well as a way to easily remove extra quotes using built-in tools.

Comment: @and31415 - That helps with the post-processing of the data.  Thanks for your clarifications!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible solution

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all results.
2. Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, and right-click the very first item in the list.
3. Choose **Copy as path** from the context menu.
4. Paste the results in a new text file.

For example, consider using the following query in the `C:\Windows\System32` folder:

```
type:image
```

The output would be something like this:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\oobe\background.bmp"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\AppInstalled.gif"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\ClickDownExpanded.gif"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\ClickDownNormal.gif"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\Column.bmp"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\Documents.gif"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\Failure.gif"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\Programs.gif"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\System.gif"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\Users.gif"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\WindowsMail.bmp"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\WindowsMovieMaker.bmp"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\WindowsOutlookExpress.bmp"
"C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\WindowsPhotoGallery.bmp"
```

### Known limitations

- Unless you select the first item in the list, the resulting output won't be sorted properly.
- All items will be enclosed in quotes.
- Copied results always include the full path.

---

## Post-processing

Just some ways to overcome the limitations.

### Manual sort

If needed, you can manually sort the output by using the `sort` command in a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7).

#### Example usage

```
sort "X:\Path\to\input.txt" /o "X:\Path\to\sorted.txt"
```

### Stripping quotes

The quotes might get in the way, but the batch script below can remove them for you. Just save it as `StripQuotes.cmd` (or whatever you like, just keep the `.cmd` extension). The script accepts two parameter: input/output files, respectively.

#### Example usage

```
StripQuotes.cmd "X:\Path\to\myfile.txt" /o "X:\Path\to\stripped.txt"
```

#### Batch script

```
@echo off
if "%~2" == "" exit /b 2
type nul>"%~2"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("%~1") do echo %%~G>>"%~2"
exit /b
```

### Retrieving file names only

In case you don't care about the full path, you can use the batch script below. The usage isn't any different from the batch script above.

#### Batch script

```
@echo off
if "%~2" == "" exit /b 2
type nul>"%~2"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("%~1") do echo %%~nxG>>"%~2"
exit /b
```